# Kotlin: Unresolved reference: use,

Tags: kotlin, chatbot, pepper

I am trying to integrate a Dialogflow Agent with Pepper: https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/lessons/integrating-chatbot-dialogflow

I followed all the steps until the [Testing your agent in standalone](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-qisdk/lessons/integrating-chatbot-dialogflow/testing-your-dialogflow-agent-standalone) section, where I have to add the following Kotlin code to the DialogflowSource class:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials
import com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.*
import java.io.InputStream

class DialogflowDataSource constructor(credentialsStream : InputStream) {
   private val credentials : ServiceAccountCredentials
       = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream)

   fun detectIntentTexts(
       text: String,
       sessionId: String,
       languageCode: String
   ): String? {
       val sessionsSettings = SessionsSettings.newBuilder()
           .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
           .build()
       SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings).use { sessionsClient ->    //Error: Unresolved reference for .use
           val session = SessionName.of(credentials.projectId, sessionId)
           val textInput = TextInput.newBuilder()
               .setText(text).setLanguageCode(languageCode)
           val queryInput = QueryInput
               .newBuilder().setText(textInput).build()
           val response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput)
           return response.queryResult.fulfillmentText
       }
   }         //Error: A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')
}
```

I'm new to Kotlin, so I don't really know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, why would you use `use`? It seems you meant to call `apply` instead. But in fact you could just write:

```kotlin
fun detectIntentTexts(
       text: String,
       sessionId: String,
       languageCode: String
   ): String? {

   val sessionsSettings = SessionsSettings.newBuilder()
       .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
       .build()
    val sessionClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings)
    val session = SessionName.of(credentials.projectId, sessionId)
    val textInput = 
        TextInput.newBuilder().setText(text).setLanguageCode(languageCode)
    val queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build()
    val response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput)
    return response.queryResult.fulfillmentText
}
```

But if you care using `use` (or `apply`), the lambda you provide to it should not directly make the outer function `detectIntentTexts` return. Instead, let your lambda return its result locally, and let `detectIntentTexts` return it:

```kotlin
   fun detectIntentTexts(
       text: String,
       sessionId: String,
       languageCode: String
   ): String? {
       val sessionsSettings = SessionsSettings.newBuilder()
           .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
           .build()
       return SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings).apply { sessionsClient ->
           val session = SessionName.of(credentials.projectId, sessionId)
           val textInput = TextInput.newBuilder()
               .setText(text).setLanguageCode(languageCode)
           val queryInput = QueryInput
               .newBuilder().setText(textInput).build()
           val response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput)
           response.queryResult.fulfillmentText
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. This is not my code. This was provided on their website, so I assumed it would work. I don't know the language well enough to understand what was wrong with the code xD